# Drupal ubercart product import with feeds

Tags: drupal, ubercart, drupal-feeds

I use Drupal 7 with Postgres database.
I created a Product importer with feeds module which is import the basic datas, but doesn't import the SKU, Cost, List price...
In this picture I only want to import the Cikkszám (SKU in English) first.
[feeds problem pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBFEM.png)

I didn't find any solution. Can anybody help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try Tamper module with plugins https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_tamper

seek for patches or go to CommerceKickstart package, it imports products easily without bugs like Ubercart has (personal experience), but is has many other troubles, Ubercart has not...

Comment: Thanks the tip. Since when I ask it I've written an own importer with PHP.